Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS app bar flickers when power plug is inserted or removed on Wayland
Ever since I upgraded to 24.04, I have noticed that on Wayland, whenever I insert or remove the charger from my laptop, the left app bar flickers. This issue only occurs on Wayland; everything works fine on X11. I've also tried the latest point release, but unfortunately, it hasn't fixed the issue yet.
Does anyone know how I can fix it?
